# ¿Contar valores en multiples columnas en R?

Tags: r

Esta es la primera vez que pregunto por acá, ya que no he conseguido resolver un problema muy básico.

1. Tengo un dataframe con 4  variables (columnas) categóricas (idénticas categorías).
2. Estoy buscando la forma de contar cuantas veces aparece cada categoría en las 4 variables de una vez. (como conjunto de respuestas multiples en SPSS).

¿Alguna sugerencia?  la función Count y Table de R solo permiten una Columna a la vez.

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido...user10187828.., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!

Answer (score 2):

No está demasiado clara tu pregunta y suscribo la sugerencia de que la modifiques para aclararla. Ayudaría muchísimo que presentes un ejemplo de tus datos.

Por lo que entiendo lo que quieres obtener el mismo resultado que que obtienes con `table()` para cada una de las columnas, solo que salga todo de una vez. Es decir, que para cada columna te muestre los conteos de cada categoría. Eso es relativamente fácil de hacer.

## Crear los datos

Como no incluyes datos en tu pregunta voy a crear unos que tienen una estructura similar a los que describes: cuatro columnas con variables categóricas (en R: factores) con las mismas categorías. En este ejemplo son dicotómicas, Sí y No. Por convención lo voy a llamar `df`

```
df <- data.frame(columna1 = c("Sí", "No", "Sí", "Sí", "No", "Sí", "Sí", "No"), 
                 columna2 = c("Sí", "No", "Sí", "Sí", "Sí", "Sí", "Sí", "Sí"),
                 columna3 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Sí"), 
                 columna4 = c("Sí", "Sí", "Sí", "Sí", "Sí", "Sí", "Sí", "No"))
```

## Aplicar una función a cada columna

La función `table()` es la función base de R para hacer conteos. Como un caso de uso muy frecuente en el análisis de datos es hacer tablas de contingencia (conteos de una variable categórica condicional a otra(s)) `table()` intenta hacer esos "cruces", a menos que le pasemos solamente una variable o columna. Para lograr lo que creo que quieres entonces debes pasar las columnas una a una a `table()`. Puedes hacerlo manualmente introduciendo una secuencia de llamadas: `table(df$columna1)`, `table(df$columna1)` y así.

Una forma más rápida es usar una función auxiliar. En este caso serviría `lapply()`. `lapply()` toma una lista (`df` es un data.frame, pero también una lista) y le pasa la función que le indiquemos a cada elemento. En este caso tu lista/data.frame es `df` y la función es `table`. Extrañamente acá no debemos usar paréntesis junto a la función, porque eso confundiría a `lapply()`.

## Resultado

```
lapply(df, table)

$columna1

No Sí 
3  5 

$columna2

No Sí 
1  7 

$columna3

No Sí 
7  1 

$columna4

No Sí 
1  7
```

El resultado es una lista de tablas, que se imprime en pantalla.

> PD: si lo que buscas es hacer una tabla de contingencia con cuatro dimensiones acláralo en la pregunta. Siempre puedes editarla.

Comment: Lo acabo de resolver.
Lo que necesitaba era una tabla con el recuento  de todas las columnas juntas.
Lo resolví con table(unlist(.....

gracias!

Comment: Que bueno! ¿Podrías modificar tu pregunta e incluir luego una respuesta con tu solución? Serviría a otras personas que consulten SO en el futuro con el mismo problema.