# ¿Contar ocurrencias de ciertas categorías en múltiples columnas?

Tags: r, r-dplyr

Voy a redefinir [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/187281/contar-valores-en-multiples-columnas-en-r) de forma más completa, ya que me parece tiene un problema interesante. El escenario es el siguiente: imaginemos que tenemos un `data.frame` con múltiples variables, estas son categóricas, por ejemplo:

```
cat1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
cat2 <- c("R1", "S2", "T3")
casos <- 10    
df <- data.frame(Col1 = c(sample(cat2, casos, replace = T)),
                 Col2 = c(sample(cat1, casos, replace = T)),
                 Col3 = c(sample(cat1[-1], casos, replace = T)),
                 Col4 = c(sample(cat2, casos, replace = T))
)
df
```

Es decir:

```
   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1    R1    B    D   S2
2    R1    C    D   S2
3    S2    A    B   R1
4    T3    D    D   S2
5    R1    D    C   R1
6    T3    B    B   R1
7    T3    D    C   T3
8    R1    A    B   T3
9    S2    B    B   S2
10   S2    B    C   T3
```

Y ahora lo que queremos es contar las ocurrencias de cada categoría en cada columna generando una tabla sumarizada como la siguiente:

```
  categorias Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1          A    0    2    0    0
2          B    0    4    4    0
3          C    0    1    3    0
4          D    0    3    3    0
5         R1    4    0    0    3
6         S2    3    0    0    4
7         T3    3    0    0    3
```

Con R base, sin duda `table()` podría ser una forma, el tema es como aplicarla a cada columna y además contemplar que eventualmente alguna categoría no aparezca en una columna (en cuyo caso la cantidad será 0), también me gustaría ver la posibilidad de resolverlo con `dplyr` si fuera posible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no hay problemas con importar `dplyr::` y `tidyr::` se puede hacer en tres líneas muy legibles.

```
library(tidyr)  #importa gather() y spread()
library(dplyr)  #importa count

cat1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
cat2 <- c("R1", "S2", "T3")
casos <- 10 
set.seed(123)    #Para test de resultados
df <- data.frame(Col1 = c(sample(cat2, casos, replace = T)),
                 Col2 = c(sample(cat1, casos, replace = T)),
                 Col3 = c(sample(cat1[-1], casos, replace = T)),
                 Col4 = c(sample(cat2, casos, replace = T))
)


gather(df, clave, valor) %>%     #A formato largo, clave = valor
  count(clave, valor) %>%        #Conteos de todas con todas
  spread(clave, n, fill = 0)     #Abrir por columna y conteo, imputar na a 0.
```

Esta paquetería ofrece una vía muy directa para reestructurar datos, que es el problema de este problema.

Comment: Excelente! me van a terminar convirtiendo a la secta de `tidyverse/dplyr`!

Comment: Lo que más me gusta es el estilo declarativo más que imperativo que tiene el paquete. Eso ayuda a pensar las soluciones sin hacer micromagement de las estructuras de datos. Es sí, la evaluación no estándar es un dolor de cabeza y escribir funciones da mucho más trabajo que con R base.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurrió básicamente es usar `table()` por cada columna e integrar todas en un único `data.frame`. No me convence mucho, son demasiadas líneas de código, pero al menos hace lo que se espera.

```
categorias <- sort(as.character(unique(unlist(df))))

m <- apply(df, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(col) {
    tb <- table(col)
    v <- as.vector(tb[match(categorias, names(tb))])
    v[is.na(v)] <- 0
    return(v)
})

data.frame(categorias, m)

  categorias Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1          A    0    2    0    0
2          B    0    4    4    0
3          C    0    1    3    0
4          D    0    3    3    0
5         R1    4    0    0    3
6         S2    3    0    0    4
7         T3    3    0    0    3
```